# How do "hos" and "kathos" compare in Ephesians 5:1-2?

Tags: ephesians

**Ephesians 5:1-2**

"Therefore be imitators of God, **as**[*hos*] beloved children. *2* And walk in love, **as** [*kathos*] Christ loved us and gave himself up for us, a fragrant offering and sacrifice to God."  ESV. My brackets and emphasis.

The first "as" looks like the second "as". What is the effect in the Greek of changing from "*hos*"[v1]  to "*kathos*" [v2]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kαθώς (*kathōs*) is a contraction of the words κατά (*kata*) and ὡς (*hōs*).  Kατά means *according to*, as in

> *Then he touched their eyes, saying, “According to your faith* [κατὰ τὴν πίστιν] *be it done to you”* (Matthew 9:29)

---

ᾨς τέκνα ἀγαπητά in Ephesians 5:1 is a sort of simile:  "Be followers of God *as* [if you were] dear children"

Kαθώς ὁ Χριστὸς ἠγάπησεν ἡμᾶς in Ephesians 5:2 means more like "*according to the way that* Christ loved us", or perhaps "*even as* Christ loved us".

Comment: +1. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Kathos* has to do with taking concrete examples or instantiations of an idea or principle that one is discussing (or here, recommending Christ's example). It's formed from *kata* (*according to*) and *hos* (*like*). Whereas *hos* is used to denote simple similitude (something is like something else).

There really isn't much more to it than this.

Answer (score 1):

According to Thayer’s Lexicon, the word hós as used in Eph 5:1 refers to a quality which belongs to a person or thing ([Strong’s 5613](https://biblehub.com/greek/5613.htm)). The word hós in Eph 5:1 appears to function as a sentential adverb, describing an entire clause rather than an individual verb. As such it is "closely related to conjunctions" ([unfoldingWord](https://ugg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adverb.html)). In Eph 5:1, hós implies that the quality of our being imitators of God is or should be characterized by our being his beloved children.

The word kathos ([Strong’s 2513](https://biblehub.com/greek/2531.htm)) is an adverb meaning “according to the manner in which, in the degree that, just as, as.” In Eph 5:2, kathos implies that we should love one another in the manner that Christ loved us.

In context, the word “hós” in Eph 5:1 is actually situated between two “kathos”, one in Eph 4:32 and the other in Eph 5:2. The change from kathos (4:32) to hós (5:1) and back to kathos (5:2) again suggests a chiastic structure. I’ve arranged the words to show that structure as follows:

```
just as (kathos) God in Christ also has forgiven you. 
   Therefore be imitators of God, 
      as (hós) beloved children; 
   and walk in love, 
just as (kathos) Christ also loved you and gave Himself up for us. 

– Eph 4:32 to 5:2 NASB
```

From this arrangement, we can see how the reality of our being God’s beloved children is key. In other words, God’s love for us is the source and center (cf 1 Jn 4:7, 19). To be imitators of God then is to walk in love. In other words, we are called to imitate God’s love for us. Furthermore, God’s example of love has two distinct aspects: 1) the love of God in forgiving us in Christ and 2) the love of Christ in offering himself as a sacrifice for us to God (cf Lk 6:36, Jn 13:34). The chiastic structure serves to bring these two aspects and everything in between together as one.

Answer (score -1):

In the phrase μιμηταὶ τοῦ Θεοῦ ὡς τέκνα ἀγαπητά; e.g., imitators of the God as children beloved (EPH 5:1), **ὡς** (hos) is a c͟o͟n͟j͟u͟n͟c͟t͟i͟o͟n. But in the phrase ἀγάπῃ καθὼς καὶ ὁ Χριστὸς ἠγάπησεν; e.g., love **as** the Christ (messiah) loved (EPH 5:2), **καθὼς** (kathōs) is an a͟d͟v͟e͟r͟b.

Comment: Disagree. Both instances are adverbs.

Comment: Conjunction connects two Clauses but adverb is for comparison. Both (as, just as) are adverbs https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/as_1

Comment: In EPH 5:2, and in the MacMillan Dictionary of American English, καθὼς (kathōs) is an adverb. But, in Koine Greek at 46, 49, and in codices 01, 02 & 03 at EPH 5:1,  ὡς (hos) is a conjunction.